Error con hydrateRoot y renderToString REACT
paso a comentarles mi problema, en sintesis, estoy utilizando DataTable y mediante una API consigo inyectarle los datos (Datos dinamicos ya que con un select modifico la tabla y su contenido). Mi problema, es que debo de crear botones dinamicos tambien, y utilizando renderToString me muestra los botones pero no me permite agregarle eventos, por tanto, decidí que era mejor utilizar hydrateRoot, pero que sucede, hydrateRoot si o si necesita un elemento padre para saber en donde debe de renderizarse. Por tanto, leí algo de que se podían combinar estas dos APIs de react, y realicé lo siguiente (Dato no menor, tengan en cuenta solamente los datos de dependencia, no probé con curso ni con alumnos xq primero quiero resolverlo acá y el resto es facil):
let nextTableData: any = [];
let newColumns: any = [];
let jsonData

const VerIngreso = () => {
  const [ajaxUrl, setAjaxUrl] = useState(`http://localhost:3000/deps`); // URL por defecto
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState();
  const [events, setEvents] = useState(0);
  const [tableKey, setTableKey] = useState(0);
  const tableRef = useRef<DataTableRef>(null);
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure();
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState([
    { data: 'dependencia', title: 'Dependencia'},
    { data: 'fecha', title: 'Fecha' },
    { data: 'ingreso', title: 'Ingreso' },
    { title: 'Acciones', data: null }
  ]);


  const selectJson = async (value: string): Promise<any[]> => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch(`http://localhost:3000/${value}`, {
        method: "GET",
      });
      if (value != 'curso')
      setAjaxUrl(`http://localhost:3000/${value}`)
      return response.json();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error:", error);
      return []; // Retorna un string vacío en caso de error
    }
  }

  // Función para actualizar el JSON y las columnas
  const changeJson = async (value: any, ret?: boolean) => {
    // Configura las columnas y URL según el valor seleccionado
    setTableData(undefined)
    switch (value) {
      case '0':
        newColumns = [
          { data: 'dependencia', title: 'Dependencia' },
          { data: 'fecha', title: 'Fecha' },
          { data: 'ingreso', title: 'Ingreso' },
          { data: 'acciones', title: 'Acciones' }
        ];
        jsonData = await selectJson('deps');
        nextTableData = jsonData.map((dato) => ({
          dependencia: dato.dependencia,
          fecha: dato.fecha,
          ingreso: dato.ingreso,
          id: dato.id,
          acciones: () => {
            return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
              <div id={`actions-${dato.dependencia}-${dato.id}`} style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", gap: "10px"}}>
                <button className="edit-btn btn-sigma" data-id={dato.id + "-" + dato.dependencia} onClick={() => onOpen()}>
                  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPenToSquare} className="text-2xl text-default-400" /></button>
                <button className="delete-btn btn-sigma"> <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashCan} className="text-2xl text-default-400" /> </button>
              </div>
            );
          },
        }));
        break;
      case '1':
        newColumns = [
          { data: 'curso', title: 'Curso' },
          { data: 'aula', title: 'Aula' },
          { data: 'fec_inicio', title: 'Fecha de Inicio' },
          { data: 'fec_finalizacion', title: 'Fecha de Finalizacion' },
          { data: 'ingreso', title: 'Ingreso' },
          { data: 'id', title: 'Acciones' }
        ];
        jsonData = await selectJson('info');
        nextTableData = jsonData.map((dato) => ({
          curso: dato.curso,
          aula: dato.aula,
          fec_inicio: dato.fec_inicio,
          fec_finalizacion: dato.fec_finalizacion,
          ingreso: dato.ingreso,
          id: () => {
            return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
            );
          }
        }));
        break;
      case '2':
        newColumns = [
          { data: 'curso', title: 'Curso' },
          { data: 'aula', title: 'Aula' },
          { data: 'fec_inicio', title: 'Fecha de Inicio' },
          { data: 'fec_finalizacion', title: 'Fecha de Finalizacion' },
          { data: 'ingreso', title: 'Ingreso' },
          { data: 'id', title: 'Acciones' }
        ];
        jsonData = await selectJson('idio');
        nextTableData = jsonData.map((dato) => ({
          curso: dato.curso,
          aula: dato.aula,
          fec_inicio: dato.fec_inicio,
          fec_finalizacion: dato.fec_finalizacion,
          ingreso: dato.ingreso,
          id: () => {
            return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(    
            );
          }
        }));
        break;
    }
    setTableKey(prevKey => prevKey + 1);
    setColumns(newColumns);
    if (ret = true)
      return nextTableData
  };

  const changeJsonForCurse = async (value: any) => {
    newColumns = [
      { data: 'dni', title: 'DNI' },
      { data: 'nombre', title: 'Nombre' },
      { data: 'mail', title: 'Mail' },
      { data: 'ingreso', title: 'Ingreso' },
    ];
    setTableData(undefined)
    jsonData = await selectJson('curso');
    nextTableData = jsonData.map((dato) => ({
      dni: dato.dni,
      nombre: dato.nombre,
      mail: dato.mail,
      ingreso: dato.ingreso
    }));
    
    setTableKey(prevKey => prevKey + 1);
    setColumns(newColumns);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    nextTableData.forEach((dato: any) => {
      if (document.getElementById(`actions-${dato.dependencia}-${dato.id}`)) {
        hydrateRoot(document.getElementById(`actions-${dato.dependencia}-${dato.id}`),
        <div id={`actions-${dato.dependencia}-${dato.id}`} style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", gap: "10px"}}>
          <button className="edit-btn btn-sigma" data-id={dato.id + "-" + dato.dependencia} onClick={() => onOpen()}>
            <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPenToSquare} className="text-2xl text-default-400" /></button>
          <button className="delete-btn btn-sigma"> <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashCan} className="text-2xl text-default-400" /> </button>
        </div>
      )
      }
      
    })
  }, [events])

  useEffect(() => {
    setTableData((t) => t = nextTableData)
    setEvents((prev) => prev+1)
  }, [columns])

  useEffect(() => {
    changeJson('0')
  }, [])

Genial! Está funcionando, lo que hago es esperar a que se cree el elemento, que el mismo me mande una señal con el useEffect cambiando el events, y luego yo, si existe el elemento, ejecuto el hydrate, entonces, cual es el problema? Que me figuran 30 errores en consola:
hook.js:608 Warning: An error occurred during hydration. The server HTML was replaced with client content in .
react-dom.development.js:6981 Uncaught Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.
See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error
react-dom.development.js:16571 Uncaught Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.
See more info here: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error

Se asume que VerIngreso esta marcado con la directiva "use client", Se puede usar dynamic import como solución temporal, pero aun se debe identificar el componente que no hace match entre el pre-render del server y el render de hydration, ¿Que version de next js estas usando?

@g.4 Buenas, efectivamente estoy usando "use client" en ese componente, la version es la 14.2.13, utilizo dinamyc imports para el apexChart, en este caso no se si podría servir, ya que el td del datatable, lo genero luego de obtener un JSON y le coloco los datos o componentes que quiero ahí, pero al hacerlo con el renderToString del lado del servidor, los eventos que le coloco (onClick x ejemplo) No se guardan, creo que estoy teniendo un mal uso del hydrateRoot, pero mepa q x ahi va la mano

Parece que nextjs esta pre-renderizando lo que hay en ReactDOMServer.renderToString, luego como tu mismo lo mencionas modificas esa pieza declarativa con useEffect despues del primer render y ahí es donde viene el missmatch de hydration, eso se soluciona condynamic import, Sería bueno si pudieras agregar mas información, tendríamos que asumir que VerIngreso se importa en un segment/page y si es así, ¿Este segment/page tiene directiva use client o es un componente server? esa es la información minima requerida para poder emular el problema de nuestro lado.

Esto es para todo aquel que esté teniendo un problema similar, la respuesta no se si es la mas efectiva o la mejor forma de hacerlo, pero, keep it simple, funciona.
Basicamente deje de lado el hydrateRoot y lo reemplace con la vieja y confiable addEventListener :D
Una vez renderizado el renderToString, le meto un ID a cada boton (Unico) Y donde hacia el mapeo para hydratar, solo agrego el evento deseado
(Hice unas pequeñas modificaciones, como por ejemplo que se ejecute la funcion cuando se modifica el tableData que termina siendo lo mismo que el events que tenia en el codigo anterior y tambien separe la funcion del useEffect)
return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
          <div id={`actions-${dato.dependencia}-${dato.id}`} style={{ display: "flex", justifyContent: "center", gap: "10px"}}>
            <button className="edit-btn btn-sigma" data-id={dato.id + "-" + dato.dependencia} id={`edit-btn-${dato.dependencia}-${dato.id}`}>
              <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPenToSquare} className="text-2xl text-default-400" /></button>
            <button className="delete-btn btn-sigma"> <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrashCan} className="text-2xl text-default-400" /> </button>
          </div>
        );

Y luego la funcion del eventHandler:
  const hydrateActions = () => {
    console.log(nextTableData)
    nextTableData.forEach((dato: any) => {
      console.log(document.getElementById(`actions-${dato.dependencia}-${dato.id}`))
      if (document.getElementById(`actions-${dato.dependencia}-${dato.id}`)) {
        document.getElementById(`edit-btn-${dato.dependencia}-${dato.id}`)?.addEventListener('click', () => alert('aaaaa'))
      }
    })
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    hydrateActions()
  }, [tableData])

  useEffect(() => {
    setTableData((t) => t = nextTableData)    
  }, [columns])

